# outlook unread mail folder integer value for jacob.jar in java

Tags: java, email, outlook, jacob

I am using JACOB. jar to access outlook . I am getting the count of my Inbox mails. how can I get the count of unread mail folder in outlook with JACOB. jar

```
Dispatch.call((Dispatch) myNamespace,"GetDefaultFolder", new Integer(6)).toDispatch();
```

with this code I am getting the count of the Inbox . I tried the values to 10 that is the integer value for contacts folder in outlook . can anyone help me to find the unread mail folder count in outlook.

Comment: Do you mean Unread Mail search folder? It is not guaranteed to exist.

Comment: So there wont be any ways to read unread mails from outlook

Comment: how can i access outlook from my java web application with JACOB.jar

Answer (score 0):

You can access that folder using Store.GetSearchFolders().Item("Unread Mail"). ***If*** that folder exists.

If it does not exist, you can use Application.AdvancedSearch to search through all folders of a particular store.

Comment: this we can use only with webmail i think . i want the outlook unread mail folder. please help me

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Are you saying your code needs to run from a remote server instead of a machine where Outlook is installed?

Comment: yes . i needs to run from a remote server instead of a machine where Outlook is installed.thanks a lot if you can help me

Comment: If the user is using a local PST file with a POP3/SMTP account, you cannot access it fro ma remote server. If an Exchange mailbox is used, you can use EWS (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877045(v=exchg.140).aspx) for remote access.